# Text shadow does not fire inside DIV but does in BODY

Tags: html, css

I have a simple test based on this codepen: https://codepen.io/davidlillo/pen/wZRagx

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pirata+One|Rubik:900');
body {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 25vh;
  background-color: #141E30;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #141E30, #0f0c29);
}

#backinblack h1 {
  text-transform: Uppercase;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: #E4E5E6;
}

#backinblack h1 {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #141E30, #0f0c29);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

#backinblack h1:before,
#backinblack h1:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#backinblack h1:before {
  z-index: -1;
  text-shadow: -0.001em -0.001em 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)
}

#backinblack h1:after {
  z-index: -2;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 20px 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), 30px 30px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div id="backinblack">
  <h1 data-text="test">test</h1>
</div>
```

The text shadow works fine when the CSS is like this:

```
body {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 25vh;
    background-color: #141E30;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #141E30, #0f0c29);
}
```

However, if I change it to have the CSS like this:

```
#backinblack {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 25vh;
    background-color: #141E30;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #141E30, #0f0c29);
}
```

And leave the HTML like this:

```
<div id="backinblack">
    <h1 data-text="test">test</h1>
</div>
```

Then the text-shadow does not appear:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pirata+One|Rubik:900');
#backinblack {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 25vh;
  background-color: #141E30;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #141E30, #0f0c29);
}

#backinblack h1 {
  text-transform: Uppercase;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: #E4E5E6;
}

#backinblack h1 {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #141E30, #0f0c29);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

#backinblack h1:before,
#backinblack h1:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#backinblack h1:before {
  z-index: -1;
  text-shadow: -0.001em -0.001em 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)
}

#backinblack h1:after {
  z-index: -2;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 20px 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), 30px 30px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div id="backinblack">
  <h1 data-text="test">test</h1>
</div>
```

I wondered why that is the case?

Comment: All you need is z-index:0 on the h1 element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because the background from #backinblack is placed above the shadow and therefore blocking it (if you remove the background from #backinblack, you'll see, the shadow is actually there), so you'll need a z-index on your #backisblack too, which only works if you set the divs position to absolute.

Add

```
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
```

to your #backinblack to change this.

More on the z-index: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pirata+One|Rubik:900');
#backinblack {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 25vh;
  background-color: #141E30;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #141E30, #0f0c29);
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
}

#backinblack h1 {
  text-transform: Uppercase;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: #E4E5E6;
}

#backinblack h1 {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #141E30, #0f0c29);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

#backinblack h1:before,
#backinblack h1:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#backinblack h1:before {
  z-index: -1;
  text-shadow: -0.001em -0.001em 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)
}

#backinblack h1:after {
  z-index: -2;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 20px 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), 30px 30px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div id="backinblack">
  <h1 data-text="test">test</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the `stacking context`. The browser paints the elements one-on-another like a stack, based on stacking order. In your example, 
the `body` will be considered as `stacking context` which means any element inside `body` will never go behind `body`. that's why it's working when you use `body` selector.

In another example, you have used `#backinblack` div element which does not have its own `stacking context`. which means anything inside `#backinblack` can go behind `#backinblack` tag if you use negative `z-index` value. that's the reason the text is not visible.

To make it work, you have to add `stacking context` to `#backinblack` in the following ways.

1. Add any `position` other than `static` and also add any `z-index` other than `auto`
2. Add `opacity` less than `1`

In the below example, I just used the 2nd technique just for creating `stacking context` and to make it work. ex.  `opacity: 0.999`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pirata+One|Rubik:900');
#backinblack {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 25vh;
  background-color: #141E30;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #141E30, #0f0c29);
  opacity: 0.999;
}

#backinblack h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: #E4E5E6;
  color: red;
}

#backinblack h1 {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #24243e, #141E30, #0f0c29);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

#backinblack h1:before,
#backinblack h1:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#backinblack h1:before {
  z-index: -1;
  text-shadow: -0.001em -0.001em 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)
}

#backinblack h1:after {
  z-index: -2;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 20px 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), 30px 30px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div id="backinblack">
  <h1 data-text="test">test</h1>
</div>
```